# Combine Sql server table's different row & column values in a Variable

Tags: sql-server-2008

For Example I have this type of data as output

```
DefectId   PMActivityId     Date                    Short_Parameter Unit Value  
    8       1       2014-07-21 18:20:03.700            WDG. RES.    R-Y    1    
    8       1       2014-07-21 18:20:03.700            WDG. RES.    Y-B    2    
    8       1       2014-07-21 18:20:03.700            WDG. RES.    B-R    3    
    8       1       2014-07-21 18:20:03.700            MEG VAL.     R-Y    4    
    8       1       2014-07-21 18:20:03.700            MEG VAL.     Y-B    5    
    8       1       2014-07-21 18:20:03.700            MEG VAL.     B-R    6    
    8       1       2014-07-21 18:20:03.700            MEG VAL.     R-E    7    
    8       1       2014-07-21 18:20:03.700            MEG VAL.     Y-E    8    
    8       1       2014-07-21 18:20:03.700            MEG VAL.     B-E    9    
    8       1       2014-07-21 18:20:03.700            Abnormality        10
```

Now i want to get the output as (for Short_parameter, Unit, Value Column Only Where DefectId =8)

WDG.RES.:R-Y:1 ,WDG.RES.:Y-B:2 , WDG.RES.:B-R:3,MEG VAL.:R-Y:4 ... and so on... 
is it possible to do? guide me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by myself.

```
DECLARE @combinedString VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  

         @combinedString = COALESCE(@combinedString + ', ', '') + (Short_Parameter + ':' + ISNULL(Unit,' ') + ':' + Value)

  FROM [EDMS_CPL].[dbo].[tblTypeOfActivityValue] WHERE DefectId=8
  print @combinedString
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the below code might help you

```
Select STUFF((SELECT ','+(select Short_Parameter+':'+Unit+':'+Value from table WHERE     DefectId=8) For XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') as 'xyz'
```